# DrupalCommerce: Alter rates retrieved from Fedex/UPS

Tags: commerce

Is it possible to alter the rates retrieved by commerce_fedex/commerce_ups modules? The actual functions to retrieve rates from an API are being called by a rule:

- `commerce_fedex_service_rate_order`
- `commerce_ups_service_rate_order`

There doesn't seem to be a hook to alter the result of that function.

Answer (score 0):

In the order of my searches,

1. There is a hook after all, to alter the result of that function, I used a Google search the terms "commerce_ups_service_rate_order
   alter" and it returned 
   https://www.drupal.org/node/1357492: Where it was pronounced fixed for the 7 version.
2. Searching my local site for "hook_commerce_shipping_service_rate_options_alter" with UPS module
   only installed, (Not Fedex too) yields 5 responses in 5 files in two folders, files result of this localized search for that:

   - commerce_shipping/commerce_shipping.api.php
   - commerce_ups/commerce_ups.module
   - commerce_deploy/commerce_deploy_shipping/commerce_deploy_shipping.module
   - commerce_shipping/commerce_shipping.api.php
   - commerce_ups/commerce_ups.module

I hope my search results have answered your question as seeming not be a hook for the functions.